# Lithium PHP framework - validation rule doesn't trigger on existing field ...

Tags: php, validation, rule, lithium

I have a form for changing password. So the POST data include the fields `password` and `passwordConfirm`.

Also I have validation rules for these 2 properties in the `Users` model, and they work fine on registration - i.e. creating new user. But when updating existing user - they don't trigger.

In that case - I dumped the data of the entity inside the `save()` method of the basic model class:

```
$entity->data()
```

I see that both submitted fields/properties are already there ... and they are different. Immediately after that I dumped

```
$entity->validates()
```

and this gives me `true` ?!?! ...

How is that even possible ??? ...

PS: I'm dumping inside a core class of the framework ... and not some 3rd party library ...

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what, if any, is missing?

Comment: Well, this is the class I'm dumping in: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/Model.php, and here you can see that on line `1118` the entity gets populated with the submitted data, and after that - on line `1124` there is a check if the data is valid. The data appears to be valid, although the `password` and `passwordConfirm` have different values. And the code for the controller and the model are here: http://pastie.org/8972857

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problem :) ...

On the validation rules, defined in the model by the previous developers, there was this clause:

`'on' => 'create'`

which was causing the validation rule not to trigger when editing.